# What are the characters not allowed in Salesforce when creating trigger names?

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to create a trigger in Salesforce wit the name:

```
 trigger (uam) on Account (after update) {
 }
```

but get the error:Unexpected token '('

Is there a regex expression or a list of characters not allowed ?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Metadata API guide on ApexTrigger](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.204.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_triggers.htm):

> The name can only contain characters, letters, and the underscore (_) character, must start with a letter, and cannot end with an underscore or contain two consecutive underscore characters.

Comment: and i assume i can build a regex expression for this ?

Comment: Is there documentation that explains the rules for creating a custom object ? I have users creating custom objects with label names over 40 characters and api name like testapinewnamefield_c__c. if i have the rules and constraints they can use those